# Use Page in a frame which was downloaded from URL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have WPF Window with Frame object,in which I want to load my xaml code received via http-request. (Request respone is URL with xaml code or file). **How I can initialize this page or load in a frame object?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XamlReader` to load XAML programmatically.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="XamlFrame" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.XamlFrame.Content = XamlReader.Parse(@"
<TextBlock
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    Text=""This is a test."" />");
    }
}
```